# SyntaxError in MIMEText and sqlite

Tags: python, sqlite, syntax, mime

This code send a notification about new article which is stored in database specified earlier in my program (this is element of RSS feeder).

```
def send_notification(article_title, article_url):
    smtp_server=smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
    smtp_server.ehlo()
    smtp_server.starttls()
    smtp_server.login('your_email@gmail.com','password')
    msg = MIMEText(f'\nHi, this is new article: {article_title}. \nYou can read this in {article_url}')
msg['Subject']='New article is available'
msg['From']='your_email@gmail.com'
msg['To']='destination_email@gmail.com'
smtp_server.send_message(msg)
smtp_server.quit()
```

I receive a message "SyntaxError: invalid syntax" for line:

```
msg = MIMEText(f'\nHi, this is new article: {article_title}. \nYou can read this in {article_url}')
```

I think it is caused by {} parentheses.
Could anyone help me to fix it?

PS I work in Python3.

Comment: there's a `'` missing at the end of `'your_email@gmail.com`

Comment: I fix it, but this mistake was caused by writing code in stackoverflow ;) Then I don't have this mistake in my real code and it doesn't work.

Comment: Did you try using format syntax? eg: `'{} {}'.format(article_title, article_url)`

Comment: You're probably using a Python version from before 3.7, where f-strings were introduced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should solve your syntax problem:

```
msg = MIMEText('\nHi, this is new article: {}. \nYou can read this in {}'.format(article_title, article_url))
```

Read more about string formatting in python [here](https://pyformat.info/)